# TypeScript export was not found

Tags: typescript, nestjs

since i updated the angular cli and nestjs versions I am getting hundreds of warnings that my custom type definitions and interfaces can not be found. But my nestjs api still works fine.

i am exporting my interface like this

```
export interface Role {...}
```

and getting this warning

```
WARNING in ./apps/api/src/app/users/dto/update-user.dto.ts 31:75-80
"export 'Role' was not found in '@project/api-datatypes'
```

my import looks like this

```
import { Role } from '@project/api-datatypes';
```

what was changed in the latest version and what do I have to do to fix those warnings?

currently i am running the following versions:

```
├── @angular/cli@11.0.6
├── @nestjs/cli@7.5.1
├── npm@6.14.4
├── nx@10.3.0
└── typescript@4.0.3
```

Comment: FWIW, the export and import are both written correctly, so this will be a tool config or path issue.

Comment: thanks @T.J.Crowder but the only thing i have changed was the nestjscli and angularcli version

Comment: my index.ts from my library looks like this export * from './role.interface';

Comment: it s possible you have wrong path on project, try to add full path without project

Answer (score 36, accepted):

just found the solution, since typescript 3.8 introduced type-only exports/import, I need to write `import type { Role } from '@project/api-datatypes';` so a simple `"type"` was missing

see link: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/leveraging-type-only-imports-and-exports-with-typescript-3-8-5c1be8bd17fb